# MEMSql join with uniouned returns 1899 bad distributed join plan

Tags: singlestore

I have events that are inserted to table game_events and other events that are inserted to table rejected_events.

I want to union them and then do bunch of joins with other data of other tables.

I run this query directly on the memSQL console:

```
 SELECT combinedEvents.*, win.*
 FROM  (
  SELECT event_id, action, status
 FROM events.game_events
 WHERE event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-17T00:00:00Z' AND '2019-12-30T23:59:59.999Z' 
 UNION  
 SELECT event_id, action,status
 FROM rejected.events
 WHERE event_arrival_time BETWEEN '2019-12-17T00:00:00Z' AND '2019-12-30T23:59:59.999Z' 
 ) AS combinedEvents  
 LEFT JOIN winner.winner_data AS win ON combinedEvents.event_id = win.event_id AND win.status = 'ACCEPTED'
```

I get from mem:

```
Error Code: 1889. Bad distributed join plan: leaf select contains sharded tables of multiple databases. Please contact technical support.
```

If I remove the JOIN - It works properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks and best regards,
Ido

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it got solved on the [MemSQL Forums](https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/join-with-uniouned-returns-1899-bad-distributed-join-plan/1495) and the solution is to move the union to the right of the join.